# UI Router Child States in Angular not Loading Controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having an issue loading controllers / templates for each child state. I have a console.log in each state controller, yet they don't fire. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Intent is to always load artist for every child state following.

```
var stateConfig = ['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
// State Configurations
$stateProvider
.state('artist', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/' + artistSlug,
  controller: "artistCtrl",
  resolve: {
    artist: function(artist){
      return artist.getArtist();
    }
  }
})
.state('events', {
  parent: 'artist',
  url: '',
  controller: 'eventsCtrl',
  templateUrl: "/templates/artist/events.html"
})
```

Comment: what is `artistSlug`? Why does `events` have empty url?

Comment: was hoping to have events resolve as a default url, while additional states would require artist as well. artistSlug is a hyphenated url string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to revise your states / params

It should go artists -> artists.artist -> artists.artist.events. Then if you go to //site.com/artists/justintimberlake/events it will resolve artist and then events

```
  var stateConfig = ['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  // State Configurations
  $stateProvider
    .state('artists', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/artists'
    })
    .state('artists.artist', {
      url: '/:artistId',
      controller: 'artistCtrl',
      template: '<div ui-view>Artist Template Wrapper for Artist and Events</div>',
      resolve: {
        artist: function (artist, $stateParams) {
          return artist.getArtist($stateParams.artistId);
        }
      }
    })
    .state('artists.artist.events', {
      url: '/events',
      controller: 'eventsCtrl',
      templateUrl: '/templates/artist/events.html',
      resolve: {
        events: function (artist, $stateParams) {
          return artist.getArtistEvents($stateParams.artistId);
        }
      }
    })
}];
```

Comment: thanks for the point, in this case, the artistId, would be the root. for ex. //site.com/justin-timberlake/events

Comment: I would think you also have a route for showing all artists in the standard CRUD model {create, read / list, update, delete}

Comment: yes there is also a state view for that, though grabbing all artists is minimally used currently

Comment: Then I would think you are going to run into state issues with having a state that starts with a parameter. My opinion is that is not a best practice. If my answer helped please mark it as answered. Thanks.